# Should ORM (Hibernate/LLBLGen etc.) files be kept separately?

Tags: git, hibernate, llblgen

Are there any benefits of keeping the ORM (Hibernate/LLBLGen etc.) files separately from the main project repo/branch (i.e. in a different repo/branch). I am not sure what is the best approach. I kind of like the idea keeping them separately but in that case, changes affect all parts of the project.

Any ideas on this issue ? What do you think is the best practice ?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as primarily opinion-based. Having said that, I'd certainly want my database to match my code at every point in my project's history. Each commit should be self-consistent.